# Customer account is temporarily disabled magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, php

I am trying to call customer login api.

```
{{url}}/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token
```

with body

```
{
    "username" : "xxxxx@gmail.com",
    "password" : "fsfsdf"
}
```

I am  getting an  error

**"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."**

But i am able to login through **magento website**.This error is getting only for particular email ids.Please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an open issue in mganeto 2.

[Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4432)

Magento2  keeps track of failed attempts to get a token with an email and the wrong password (in the `oauth_token_request_log` table). If the failures_count column reaches the max allowed value (which is 6 by default). then authentication fails.

A temporary solution that i have done, is running  cron job that does this cleanup on the database.

```
DELETE FROM oauth_token_request_log;
```

The above SQL will runs in every 1 minute.

Comment: You may compromise your security by running this (bruteforce attack). But it is still a very good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

please can you tell me how to run this DELETE FROM oauth_token_request_log;
?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/194900)